# How to reduce the contacts loading time?

Tags: android

I am developing an app which loads the contacts from phone,i am facing a problem of time taken by the contacts at loading from phone ,it takes much time when the contacts are loaded .I have tried two different views for displaying the contacts but loading time did not get affected.

I am picking contacts name as well as phone numbers of four types like mobile , work,home and other.
Please guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you populating the listview with contacts provider data?Post the code!

Answer (score 0):

btnPick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        //intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);

        // startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);

        }
        });
```

this is d code that pass d intent to the contect & so not it is the time consuming

and also add in manifeast